# Cloud Build kubectl - How to Apply Output of Previous Step to Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, bazel, kubectl, google-cloud-build

I have a simple `cloudbuild.yaml` file which runs a Bazel command. This command returns a Kubernetes configuration in form as a log output.

My goal is to take the output of the first step and apply it to my Kubernetes cluster.

```
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/bazel
    args: ["run", "//:kubernetes"]

  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl"
    args: ["apply", "<log output of previous step>"]
    env:
      - "CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=europe-west3-a"
      - "CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER=cents-ideas"
```

## Update

I've tried the following:

```
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/bazel
  entrypoint: /bin/bash
  args:
    [
      "bazel",
      "run",
      "//:kubernetes",
      " > kubernetes.yaml",
    ]

- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl"
  args: ["apply", "-f", "kubernetes.yaml"]
  env:
    - "CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=europe-west3-a"
    - "CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER=cents-ideas"
```

But then I get this error:

```
Running: kubectl apply -f kubernetes.yaml
error: the path "kubernetes.yaml" does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everyone already suggested here use [volumes](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#volumes).

Tweak your `cloudbuild.yaml` file like this:

```
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/bazel
  entrypoint: /bin/bash
  args:
    [
      "bazel",
      "run",
      "//:kubernetes",
      " > /workspace/kubernetes.yaml",
    ]

- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl"
  args: ["apply", "-f", "/workspace/kubernetes.yaml"]
  env:
    - "CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=europe-west3-a"
    - "CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER=cents-ideas"
```

Comment: /workspace is a default volume shared by all containers for your convenience. You don't need to mount it explicitly. You can attach custom volumes following documentation provided.

Comment: unfortunately: `error: the path "/workspace/kubernetes.yaml" does not exist`

Comment: I tested it myself with [this example](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#volumes) and it worked just fine with either custom volume or `/workspace` default volume. So the error originates in step 1, during `bazel run`. Can you check if it actually outputs anything to `/stdout` during build by running only with `args: ["run", "//:kubernetes"]`. If it doesn't output anything then `kubernetes.yaml` is not created and leads to error in next step. Also you don't need "bazel" argument in first step. It is there by default.

Comment: Oh, forgot about entrypoint, please disregard my last remark from previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to mount the volume:

https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#volumes

Basically add:

```
  volumes:
  - name: 'vol1'
    path: '/persistent_volume'
```

Then reference full path `/persistent_volume/filename/` when writing / reading to your file.

Comment: That seems like the way to go... but I always get errors that my path does not exist. Is there a way to see the volume directories?

Comment: you would just add an `ls` command.
Create another step with `ls` for each directory you want.